# How to make an image cover full window from 50% to the right

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4, grid

Can anyone please [image]help me with my issue?
I'm working with the bootsrap 4, and I'm have to find a solution to this case:
I have one element that is located into the standard six columns.
However the socond element occupies a full width of page, I have to place them to the next of each other.
I attached a picture of design for an idea of ​​what it should look like.
Please, please help me I'm quite desperate.

Thank you,
Lukas

Comment: does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you set `max-width: 100%;` for all the `img` tags, use `max-width: none` for the image in the second six columns of your provided picture, and if you used `.img-fluid` class in this image, remove it, `.img-fluid` class has the CSS of `max-width: 100%;` see the demo in full screen.

### Demo

```css
body {overflow-x: hidden}
img {max-width: none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x600/74bdcc/fff.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use this if the image is *sized* or *layered*  for that specific dimension, if not, then use `width: 50vw;` for that image, see the example below-

```css
img {width: 50vw}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x600/74bdcc/fff.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```